# GCC: pc-relative load offset out of range

Tags: gcc, arm

I am running build on RH7 machine with GCC 4.8.5 version with Arm machine (Architecture:aarch64)
Build exiting with below error:

> ```
> /tmp/ccKS41VR.s: Assembler messages:
> /tmp/ccKS41VR.s:64031: Error: pc-relative load offset out of range   
> /tmp/ccKS41VR.s:64051: Error: pc-relative load offset out of range
> ```

On x86_64 machines I am not seeing such issues while building. Do we need to setup any configs specific to GCC on aarch64 machine?